# The problem with the launch of the project gulp

Tags: reactjs, npm, gulp, environment-variables

Can't run project. 
When you enter the "gulp default", errors do not occur. 
When you enter "serve serve", this error is displayed:

```
Browserify Error { Error: Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you
specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are
"development", "test", and "production". Instead, received: undefined.
While processing preset:
"C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\yarmobile.local\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-
app\\index.js") while parsing file:
C:\OpenServer\domains\yarmobile.local\src\app\main.js
```

Comment: What's the issue? The error seems pretty clear. Specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV`.

Comment: gulpfile.js

gulp.task('set-production', function() {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});

gulp.task('set-development', function() {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
});

Comment: does your set-development task name included in default task array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your gulp file should contain the below-mentioned task.

```
gulp.task('serve', ['set-development']);
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```